# Pagespeed - cdn.com/framework.css + mysite.com/custom.css VS mysite.com/customframework.css

Tags: performance, twitter-bootstrap, cdn, pagespeed

There are lots of CSS frameworks out there and this might be applicable to js as well but i'll use twitter bootstrap for an example.

Is it recommended to compile a custom version of the framework (using sass for example) which will be hosted on your site 
OR
Use a framework cdn and a small theme stylesheet to overwrite the default style which is hosted on your site?

e.g

```
<!-- bootstrap cdn -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<!-- custom theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="mysite/css/custom-bootstrap-theme.min.css">
```

OR

```
<!-- custom boostrap -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="mysite/css/custom-bootstrap.min.css">
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally speaking, you want to minimize the number of requests the browser has to make to obtain the resources, so one script (or style) is better than two.

However, the CDN you are using might provide much better latency and download speed than your own server, and in this case, it might be faster to grab the style in parts (fast download from CDN for the bulk of the content and a slower download of less content from your server).

The *best* option would be to use a single script (a "bundle") which is minified (like you have done) and CDNified (i.e. you want your own script to be served from a CDN, like Amazon CloudFront for example).